# Built-in nodejs path aliasing and implied index.js module resolution

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to set up import path aliasing in a typescript/node/express project WITHOUT using other packages like tsconfig-paths and link-module-alias. I would like to do this with built-in nodejs functionality (the Typscript aliasing is already done).

Basically:

```js
// Change
import { myFn } from '../../../utils';

// To
import { myFn } from '#this/utils';
```

The glimmer of hope I have is with node's [subpath imports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-imports). Theoretically, I can just add this to my `package.json`:

```json
"imports": {
    "#this/*": "./dist/*"
}
```

### Here's the problem

This works for explicitly importing the `*.js` files, but it does fails for implied `index.js` (i.e. [Folders as modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#folders-as-modules))

```js
// Works
import { myFn } from '#this/utils/index.js';

// Does not work
import { myFn } from '#this/utils';
```

However, I would expect node to resolve the import like this:

- if utils is a directory, the import should resolve to `*/utils/index.js`
- if utils is a file, the import should resolve  to `*/utils.js`

My first thought would be to update the package.json imports to include all possibilities, but this is not supported:

```
"imports": {
    "#this/*": [
        "./dist/*",
        "./dist/*.js",
        "./dist/*/index.js"
    ]
}
```

The other option seems to be to define an `exports` entry for every directory, but that is not scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` flag the code below works for me.

`index.js:`

```js
import { myFn } from '#this';
```

`package.json:`

```json
...
  "imports": {
    "#this": "./utils"
  }
...
```

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me on a typescript node project using esbuild was to define the path twice, but for the second time don't include `/*`. That will allow you to import the `index.ts` using `@utils` while still allowing you to import other files underneath the directory

```json
{
  "paths": {
    "@src/*": ["src/*"],
    "@src": ["src"],
    "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
    "@utils": ["src/utils"]
  }
}
```